# "Match of the century" in Reykjavik

Tags: museums, iceland, reykjavik

The so called [Match of the Century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1972) was the chess world championship between Boris Spassky and Bobby Fischer in Reykjavik, Iceland, in 1972. It's one of the most famous chess matches because it took place during the "Cold war", between an American and a Russian and Bobby Fischer's victory ended the hegemony of Russian players in the World Chess Championship.

Is there something commemorating this event left in Reykjavik, like a chess museum, themed bar or else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Icelandic National Museum](http://www.thjodminjasafn.is/english) had a [temporary exhibition](http://www.thjodminjasafn.is/syningar/sersyningar/eldri-syningar/nr/3379) in 2012 for the 40th anniversary together with the Icelandic [Chess Federation](http://www.skaksamband.is/) to commemorate the event where they showed (among others) the original tournament board, table and chairs.

After that, they moved the artifacts to the newly opened [Bobby Fisher Center](http://fischersetur.is/index.cfm?page=pages/start_en3&lang=en) in Selfoss, where he is also buried. So if you go there you can also visit [Bobby Fischers grave](http://wikimapia.org/19934920/Bobby-Fischer-grave), just as [Kasparov did](http://www.reykjavikopen.com/historic-moment-for-chess-kasparov-at-fischers-grave/) this year.

Beware that center is about 60km away from Reykjavik and opens only 2 hours per day, is closed in Winter, but you can get in by appointment.